# Is there a fixed point representation available in C or Assembly

Tags: c, assembly, x86

As far as I know, representing a fraction in `C` relies on floats and doubles which are in `floating point` representation.

Assume I'm trying to represent `1.5` which is a fixed point number (only one digit to the right of the radix point). Is there a way to represent such number in C or even assembly using a `fixed point` data type?

Are there even any `fixed point` instructions on `x86` (or other architectures) which would operate on such type?

Comment: There is no universal assembly language, and nobody knows which one you are using because you did not tag your question with a particular processor architecture or mention it in your question. Every integer format is a fixed-point format, with the point fixed at zero digits. Regular add and subtract instructions work the same way on all fixed-point formats; they are identical for integer and other fixed-point formats. Multiplies and divides result in scaling, so a fixed-point multiply can be done with an integer multiplied followed by a shift (if the fixed-point base is a power of two).

Comment: Some processor architectures have instructions that assist with fixed-point operations, such as a multiply with a shift included.

Comment: Do you mean decimal fixed point or binary? As written ("one digit to the right of the radix point") it sounds like you're talking about decimal here, although 1.5 has the property that it's also just 1 digit in binary (1.1).

Comment: but I can't represent 1.5 as an int, can I?

Comment: E.g., suppose your fixed-point format is such that an integer x in a register represents the value x/s. (If s is 10, this is a one-decimal-digit fraction-part fixed-point format. If s is 256, it is an eight-bit fraction-part fixed-point format.) Then if two registers contain a and b, representing a/s and b/s, and you add them, getting (a+b), that represents (a+b)/s, so the add is done. If you multiply them, you get ab, which represents ab/s, but you need ab/s^2, so you then have to divide by s. So multiplying two registers and then dividing by s gives you a fixed-point multiplication.

Comment: State which processor architecture(s) you will target. State whether you want binary or decimal fixed-point or something else, or state what properties you need.

Comment: @Josh: Bits are just bits. We can say they represent anything we want them to represent. Very often, we put a bunch together and say they represent an integer. There are plenty of instructions that operate on them as if they represent integers. But do not be misled into thinking they **are** integers. If we way the bits 110110 represent 3.14, then they do. It is just up to us to make the software and hardware manipulate them in the way we want so that the representations work. So we can show you how to make a fixed-point type using “integers.” You just need to answer some questions.

Comment: But why would it matter if it binary or decimal, I thought fixed point is any fraction with fixed number of digits after the decimal point.

Comment: @Josh: Suppose I am an accountant, and I write so many figures during the day, I try to save time and never write decimal points. I just write “342” and know it is “3.42”. In fact, I have a ledger with preprinted forms with a line running down it, so I write the “3” on one side and the “42” on another. That is a fixed-point format. Where the point is is fixed. But nobody said it has to be decimal. Accounts use that. In computers, we use binary most often. I have registers with, say, 32 bits. I can run an imaginary line through them and say 24 bits are the integer part and 8 are the fraction.

Comment: ok but I also thought, from a circuit design point of view, `floating point` numbers are hard wired to `floating point` registers. You can put `3.42` on a regular register but you can't do any floating point arithmetic on it, is that right?

Comment: @Josh: The number of digits after the decimal point depends on the base. 1/3 has 1 digit after the radix point in base 3, and infinitely many in base 10.

Answer (score 4):

Every integral type can be used as a fixed point type.  A favorite of mine is to use int64_t with an implied 8 digit shift, e.g. you store 1.5 as `150000000` (1.5e8).  You'll have to analyze your use case to decide on an underlying type and how many digits to shift (that is, assuming you use base-10 scaling, which most people do).  But 64 bits scaled by 10^8 is a pretty reasonable starting point with a broad range of uses.

Comment: is there an advantage to use this method over `floats` and `doubles`?

Comment: @Josh: See [Floating point versus fixed point: what are the pros/cons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3692738/floating-point-versus-fixed-point-what-are-the-pros-cons), for starters. In large part, if your numbers will vary widely in magnitude, especially by amounts not know when writing the code, floating-point is preferable. Fixed-point may be preferable when its range is satisfactory because floating-point often has a higher hardware or performance burden.

Comment: @Josh: Some applications use fixed point instead of floating point to represent currency because fixed point does not lose accuracy (so long as you don't try to represent tiny amounts like 1e-15 dollars, which in most applications would never happen).

Comment: When you say Fixed point is just an integer, what does that mean? 1 as a decimal is also a fixed point? but it doesn't have a point , I would think 1.0 would make a fixed point (since it has a point)

Comment: @Josh: Read about fixed point on Wikipedia or similar.  Whereas floating point is commonly implemented as a mantissa and exponent (two integers), fixed point is commonly implemented as a single integer with a constant, known, fixed exponent (aka scale factor).  For example the machine integer 1500 might mean 0.015 or 0.15 or 1.5 or 15 or 150 depending on the scale factor defined in the specification of the particular fixed point type in use.

Answer (score 2):

While some C compilers offer special fixed-point types *as an extension* (not part of the standard C language), there's really very little use for them. Fixed point is just integers, **interpreted with a different unit**. For example, fixed point currency in typical cent denominations is just using integers that represent cents instead of dollars (or whatever the whole currency unit is) for your unit. Likewise, you can think of 8-bit RGB as having units of 1/256 or 1/255 "full intensity".

Adding and subtracting fixed point values with the same unit is just adding and subtracting integers. This is just like arithmetic with units in the physical sciences. The only value in having the language track that they're "fixed point" would be ensuring that you can only add/subtract values with matching units.

For multiplication and division, the result will not have the same units as the operands so you have to either treat the result as a different fixed-point type, or renormalize. For example if you multiply two values representing 1/16 units, the result will have 1/256 units. You can then either scale the value down by a factor of 16 (rounding in whatever way is appropriate) to get back to a value with 1/16 units.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding it, so based on what you are saying, `1.23 + 2.34` is the same as `123 + 234` ? they are just integers?

Comment: Yes. If you're working with fixed point in 1/100 units ("cents" for example) then you just represent 1.23 as 123, 2.34 as 234, and print a `.` before the last 2 digits when printing them. If you multiply two such values together, e.g. 123*234=28782, you'll now be in units of 1/10000, and to get back to units of 1/100 you need to divide by 100 and round in some manner (yielding, in the example, 288). This matches 1.23 * 2.34 ~= 2.88.

Comment: is that how CPUs without floating point instructions manage to do fraction arithmetic?

Comment: Fixed point libraries are common in the embedded world, where precision and/or speed are important.  Due to the general purpose registers and accumulators in most processors, you can always do some sort of fixed point math in registers or between registers and memory using a single instruction, but on systems that lack a floating point processor, floating point requires multiple operations.

Comment: @Josh: In some cases, *applications* meant to run on cpus without hardware floating point are written to use fixed point. However, if you're running code using floating point types on a cpu without floating point instructions, there's more elaborate library code performing all the operations. Since the exponent (position of the radix point) can vary in floating point, the code has to extract that, treat it as a variable, and line up the places accordingly to add/subtract.

Comment: When you say Fixed point is just an integer, what does that mean? `1` as a decimal is also a fixed point? but it doesn't have a `point` , I would think `1.0` would make a fixed point (since it has a point)

Answer (score 0):

If the issue here is representing decimal values as fixed point, there's probably a library for this for C, you could try a web search. You could create your own BCD fixed point library in assembly, using the BCD related instructions, AAA (adjusts after addition), AAS (adjusts after subtraction) and AAM (adjusts after multiplication). However, it seems these instructions are invalid in X86 X64 (64 bit) mode, so you'll need to use a 32 bit program, which should be runnable on a 64 bit OS.

Financial institutions in the USA and other countries are required by law to perform decimal based math on currency values, to avoid decimal -> binary -> decimal conversion issues.

Comment: AMD64 removed them, and they're slowish anyway.  You could maybe `pushf`/`pop` to read AF manually.  But why would you want packed or unpacked BCD at all, though (at a cost of 1 `adc` per byte, or `adc` + `daa`, instead of simply an integer part and a fractional part?  You can modulo reduce the fractional part to a power of 10 to make it a decimal fraction (e.g. a 32-bit fractional part out of 10^9).  BTW, financial stuff might use decimal *floating* point, which has hardware support on POWER for example.

Comment: @PeterCordes - IBM and other mainframes support packed or unpacked decimal integer math, and software is used to handle fixed or variable point formats. For example [IBM decimal instructions](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSENW6_1.6.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r3.asma400/asmr1021105.htm) . Cobol also supports packed or unpacked decimal.